How to upgrade eclipselink in Payara server?
I would like to upgrade Eclipselink in Payara server 6.2024.6 to version 4.0.3.
I followed what stated in upgrading the version of eclipselink being used in payara server and older Upgrading eclipselink 2.4 in Netbeans but the new jars are not loaded correctly.
Extracted from the server log:
Failed to install file:/C:/payara/payara6/glassfish/modules/org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3339)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version "4.0.3- SNAPSHOT.v202405161415": non-numeric "3-SNAPSHOT"
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3-SNAPSHOT"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)

What can I do ?

Where did you get the new Eclipselink JAR from? It looks like its OSGi manifest contains a snapshot version and not a final version. As a workaround, open the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file and change the version from 4.0.3- SNAPSHOT.v202405161415 to 4.0.3

I downloaded the OSGi bundle from the link found on https://www.eclipse.org/

Those binaries are corrupted, see my reply below.

There's a bug in the binaries distributed in EclipseLink download page at  https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/#download. They contain a snapshot version in the OSGi manifest which is not expected by the Felix OSGi container in Payara. I raised a bug for the EclipseLink project here.
However, the artifacts released in Maven Central have correct version in the OSGi manifest. You can download them from: https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.eclipse.persistence
